# Github Pages No Longer Builds

Tags: github, jekyll, github-pages

I have a working github pages blog [here.](http://cole-maclean.github.io/) -See update below- After adding a new blog post and pushing the update, I received an email from github indicating "Page Build Failure". I can successfully build and serve the site using jekyll locally without issue.

After 22 attempted fixes and subsequent gh build failures, I am at a loss. The base of my blog is built of off [this](https://github.com/cole-maclean/fengzhichu-theme), and I have cloned a fresh copy into my personal blog in an attempt to build fresh from this template. I now get the same build error when pushing this clean template directory.

The only info the github email gives is:

"The page build failed with the following error:

Page build failed"

Has something changed on githubs side that breaks the linked template? Is anyone able to get github to successfully build that template now? I have been successfully updating this blog as recently as August 12th, has something changed in the past couple weeks that has broken my site?

The repo for the site is [here](https://github.com/cole-maclean/cole-maclean.github.io)

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

-pH+

Update: I attempted to start completely fresh by deleting the working site and following the steps of the template instructions, without success, so the above link will now give a 404 site not found error.

Comment: When working locally, did you use the option `--safe` with `jekyll serve`?

Comment: @wasthishelpful yes i'm using bundle exec jekyll serve --safe locally, and it builds and serves without issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to figure out why github pages suddenly was unable to build this template, but I've found a work around by compiling the page locally and pushing that to github. [This](http://ixti.net/software/2013/01/28/using-jekyll-plugins-on-github-pages.html) article provides a step by step guides on how to publish to github pages using this technique.

Essentially you need to locally compile and push using the following script in the local Rakefile:

```
require "rubygems"
require "tmpdir"

require "bundler/setup"
require "jekyll"


# Change your GitHub reponame
GITHUB_REPONAME = "ixti/ixti.github.com"


desc "Generate blog files"
task :generate do
 Jekyll::Site.new(Jekyll.configuration({
   "source"      => ".",
    "destination" => "_site"
  })).process
end


desc "Generate and publish blog to gh-pages"
task :publish => [:generate] do
Dir.mktmpdir do |tmp|
cp_r "_site/.", tmp

pwd = Dir.pwd
Dir.chdir tmp

system "git init"
system "git add ."
message = "Site updated at #{Time.now.utc}"
system "git commit -m #{message.inspect}"
system "git remote add origin git@github.com:#{GITHUB_REPONAME}.git"
system "git push origin master --force"

Dir.chdir pwd
  end
end
```